# Readline() is giving me blank space in output

Tags: python, database, search, readline

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to make a database with Add and Search features without a library. Everything is going fine, except that when the compiler sees that the word is in the text file and I tell it to readline(), it gives me a blank space. Here's my code:

```
data = open("C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Python Course\Course\Advanced Python\Exam\data.txt", "a+")  

x = input ("Would you like to add or search?")
if x == "Add".lower():

data.write(input("Please enter: (Name,Age,Address,Date of birth,blood type,type(doctor,nurse,patient),disease,Married(yes or no)"))
      data.write('\n')
   
def search():
    if x == "Search".lower():
      y = input ("What would you like to search for? (Name,age,type)")

    if y == "Name".lower():
      z = input("Who would you like to search for?")
        
      with open("C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Python Course\Course\Advanced Python\Exam\data.txt", "r") as f:
        if z in f.read():
          print(f.readline())

search()
```

If anyone can tell me how I can fix it, I'd appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to print the line, where `z` was found or what are you trying to do?

Comment: Using ```f.read()``` reads the file, but after that you are at the end of the file and readline or read will return only empty space. If you want to fix this, save the contents of the file to a string, or save the position you are at whilst performing the search
I won't write a complete answer, since this seems like a homework assignment and you will learn the most by trying it yourself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question for formattin

Comment: @user56700 yes that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like:

```
with open("C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Python Course\Course\Advanced Python\Exam\data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if z in line:
            print(line)
```

Please note it will print out all matching lines. If you just want to print the first occurrence, you could break the for loop when a match is found:

```
with open("C:\\Users\PC\Desktop\Python Course\Course\Advanced Python\Exam\data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if z in line:
            print(line)
            break
```

Comment: And since a text file is iterable you can drop the call to `readlines` and simply use: `for line in f:`

Comment: @Matthias you are, of course, correct, thanks for the reminder. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias for the feedback!

Comment: I have just one last question, when I search for something that exists twice, it gives me only the first one. Is there any way to fix this?